# Adding a new member variable to existing java POJO

Tags: java, constructor, pojo

Hi want to add new field boolean hasXYZ to an existing class which has two member variables. This class is widely used in the code and I want to add the new field in a way that I do not want to change all of the 
`new demoClass()` calls to include the new field hasXYZ. And I was hasXYZ more like a on demand field .. so effectively, I guess two set of constructor .. one which works and other which takes additional boolean and sets hasXYZ. Thoughts on how I can do this ?

```
@Value
@NonFinal
public class demoClass implements demoInterface {
    int integerMember;
    long longMember;
}
```

Comment: what is the default vaue for hasXYZ ? and and logic to set it?

Comment: default value is false. And there is use case where another class will set it to true .. if need be

Comment: why not extending that class?

Comment: Would putting a default method in the interface help.  It won't affect existing or future implementations but will add additional capability.

Comment: @WJS I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment.

Answer (score 1):

Overload the constructor:

```
public class demoClass implements demoInterface {
    int integerMember;
    long longMember; // these should probably be private
    boolean hasXYZ;

    public demoClass( int integerMember, long longMember) {
        this.integerMember = integerMember;
        this.longMember = longMember;
    }


    public demoClass( int integerMember, long longMember, boolean hasXYZ) {
        this.integerMember = integerMember;
        this.longMember = longMember;
        this.hasXYZ = hasXYZ;
    }
}
```

Then you won't have to modify how you create the objects.

Comment: You should also show setting a default value explicitly. And maybe the shorter constructor calling the longer one.

Comment: Is there no way to do these using annotation ? instead of explicit constructors ?

Comment: @Andy897 I don't think so. I've never see it at least. Also, comment from Basil is good. That stuff should be done